# Is there something in emacs package system equivalent to gemfile and gemfile.lock in ruby projects?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In other words, is there a best practice to manage version, dependencies, etc of emacs packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cask](https://github.com/rejeep/cask.el) is the closest you will get to Ruby Gem management.  Due to limitations in Emacs package management there are some shortcomings though, for instance there is no way to fix dependencies to a specific version.

But I am of the opinion that sophisticated dependency management is not really required in Emacs Lisp, anyway.  After all, it's still an extension language for a text editor, however sophisticated, and no dollars are lost and no children die if some dependency breaks.

Disclaimer:  I am one of the maintainers of Cask.